# How come the unit of range not displayed in theme editor in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I am building a shopify theme, and I am not sure why I cannot see the unit in range element in theme editor. It is displayed in theme settings as you can see here.

[image]

But when it comes to schema of section file, the unit is not displayed. Like

[image]
Even tho I added unit in schema.

[image]

How could this get solved? Is it a Shopify's error or am I doing something wrong?
All the replies will be appreciated.

Comment: you need to set the `unit: '%'` to show it into backend editior

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: can able to share the JSON code for the settings, where % is shown into the backend editor?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/BAZ1rO
I shared section file here

Comment: all instances of range on the same code files are not working or that ones only that are code by you custom?

Comment: No, some of them works, but others don't work. So I am wondering if it is due to Shopify's error

Comment: okay, I think the issue with the default value, where you set the default to 0, doesn't work and where you set is greater than it works well. you can check and confirm the same?

Comment: If default value is out of min/max value, theme won't be deployed, so I am sure the default is not the problem here

Comment: Yup, quite weird, I have check and test the value with 0 also, and works well, no issues with 0. https://prnt.sc/1681gju

Comment: So maybe Shopify's err do you think? :)

Comment: Might be an issue on the Shopify end, due to a lot of JSON code into the schema, or something else? I think you also connect the theme developer also, because it is paid theme after all

Comment: Yeah, I think so. But this theme is not paid theme, this is not finished yet, and I have been building it for 10 months

Comment: okay, I saw some text regarding the outofthesandbox, so I think this is a paid theme

Comment: That is link to be fixed. Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it

Comment: did you find a solution for it?